# How to bind Gridview with data at runtime in Windows Phone 7?

Tags: silverlight, windows-phone-7, gridview, windows-phone-7.1, observablecollection

In table creation, listbox method doesnt suits to my project need as the table goes beyond phone view. Gridview suited exactly. But I dont know how to add rows at runtime.Could anyone help me please?

```
namespace myApp
{
    public class Person
    {
        public string Id { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public Person(string dId, string dName)
        {
            this.Id = dId;
            this.Name = Name;            
        }
    }
}
```

This is my XAML code:

```
 <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Background="Transparent">
        <gridView:GridView x:Name="GridView1" CellSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1" ItemsSource="{Binding}">
            <gridView:GridView.Columns>
                <gridView:GridViewTextColumn Header="ID" Binding="{Binding} />
                <gridView:GridViewTextColumn Header="Name" Binding="{Binding}"/>

            </gridView:GridView.Columns>
        </gridView:GridView>
    </Grid>
```

To create Statically, i have no problem that I created an **viewmodel** for person object(e.g personVM) and I created static resource(in XAML) to that object and bound with my gridview.

```
<phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources> 
<local:PersonViewModel x:Key="PersonVM"/> 
</phone:PhoneApplicationPage.Resources>    

<gridView:GridView x:Name="GridView1" CellSpacing="1" RowSpacing="1" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource PersonVM}, Path=Data}"
>
```

How to do this dynamically? (it can be done by **observablecollection??)**I cant do with datacontext.

```
GridView1.DataContext = new Person("S403","Arthos");
```

Its not working.How can I identify columns in code.Help me please.

Comment: Your gridview can be accessed via the object "GridView1" . In your VS2010, just type "GridView1." and the autocomplete opens up. I'm sure something like add column exists somewhere. Good luck finding :)

Comment: No dude, I have no way to identify columns. Gridview1.Columns is the only hope. But how could identify a column with columns property(this property is to add columns to gridview).

Comment: Yes that's it! Columns is a COLLECTION. use "Gridview1.Columns." and check the autocomplete. There will be an add somewhere :)

Comment: Gridview1.columns.Add is just to add columns, I couldnt find anything relevant :(

Comment: I'm sorry. You need to ass a ROW not a column. using "GridView1.Rows.Add" , if you can't get the binding right. In you c# code, use an iterator to load all your data into GridView1 one by one. ; well that's how bindings sorta works anyway :)

Comment: You have no row property in windows Phone. That's the issue!

Comment: Really? Starting up my VS.  Gimme a min :)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/8028/discussion-between-prakash-bala-and-akshay)

Comment: I think what you are looking for is not GridView but a normal GRID. It has both row and column properties :); So add a grid tag under your main layout.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Building a DataGrid Control for Silverlight for Windows Phone

http://www.silverlightshow.net/items/Building-a-DataGrid-Control-for-Silverlight-for-Windows-Phone-Part-1.aspx

This suits the way to create a dynamic table perfectly, The problem in using list box is if the contents goes beyind windows phone, its not easy then to create table using listbox. Then i cant find any way to find dynamically access the grid view.

This(link) grid control has lot of features that would help a newbie like me. Its totally intuitive.